# PackageManager not found using android and phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova

```
package com.example.JQmTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///home/dotcue/JQmTest/assets/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

I use this code and i am getting following error.

Error:(7, 8) java: cannot access android.content.pm.PackageManager
  class file for android.content.pm.PackageManager not found

I am very new to android and phonegap. Kindly help me. Thank you

Comment: where you use PackageManager i didn't find it ?

Comment: I did't use PackageManager anywhere in that code, But i am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

I just write this following.And it working fine for me.

I think the error is because of your syntax of **loadUrl**.Change like below hope it will work.

```
package com.demoapp;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class EOSActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);



    }
}
```

Add the following code in your **manifest**.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: When i modify like above code i am getting "Target package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml"